# ng-repeat without filter - Calculate total

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am using `ng-repeat` and managing filter using `ng-hide/ng-show` rather than filter as the filtering is complex and the collection is quite big (thousands of rows with lots of columns). Following is a representative of my `ng-repeat`.

```
<tr ng-show="(verticalFilter==0 || j.Vertical_Id==verticalFilter) && (!searchText || j.vJobNo.indexOf(searchText) !== -1)"
    ng-repeat="j in jobs" ng-class="$even ? 'odd' : 'even'">
```

I can calculate the sum of one of the columns (any no of columns) easily by calculating it once. However, I need to update the total when I change the filter. Mind, I am not using filter like `ng-repeat="a in data | filter: myfilter"` and so I am facing a challenge.

Can someone help?

Comment: could you insert plunker please

Comment: How are you updating the filter variable? Have whatever event updates the filter variable also re-calculate the total.

Comment: @georgeawg, I'm not sure how I may be able to recalculate. On change of the filter condition, the data array is still the same. Do you mean, I apply all the filter rules while calculating the total? That might be one idea. I shall try and update here. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @georgeawg. I just took the cue from your comment and implemented the feature. Thanks.